# Windows won't boot: Disk Error. What are my options?

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

I have a Dell XPS convertible laptop. The other day it would not boot, it just got stuck at the Dell logo with a spinning animation.

I booted it into the BIOS diagnostic suite, which reported no errors, including in thorough mode, including the hard drive.

I created a Windows recovery USB flash drive, and booted into that. Startup repair failed (stuck at logo + spinner), system restore and other options result in a blue screen (as in, just a blue screen, not a BSOD).

I tried to go through the Install Windows route from the same flash drive, but it said some drivers were missing, and it couldn't even start.

I then disabled UEFI and tried a Hard Disk legacy boot. It now says:

```
Disk error
Press any key to restart
[keypress]
Reboot or Select proper Boot device
or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key
[keypress]
Disk error
Press any key to restart
[etc.]
```

It seems the Drive (SSD) is borked, is there any way out of this situation other than replacing it? It's a screwless chassis I think, so if there's a chance of salvaging it without going down that route that would be preferred.

Comment: We really need more details about exactly what steps you took. There are a lot of assumptions we have to make to answer your question. What is your end goal here? To recover the data? To make windows boot again? To just start over fresh? How did you make the “windows recovery” flash drive? You can’t change UEFI to legacy. That definitely isn’t going to fix your problem.

Comment: @Appleoddity The end goal is to recover the data and get the machine back to how it was before it broke: it boots into Windows with my data in place. I made the flash drive using a Mac, and the windows 10 ISO image downloaded from Microsoft.